# Login via facebook and gmail

Tags: java, facebook, kotlin, spring-security, gmail

I have an application which is based on JWT.

Currently, when you log in with account created via application - you get jwt token:

```
@PostMapping("/authenticate")
    fun createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody authenticationRequest: AuthenticationRequest): ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.username, authenticationRequest.password)
            )

        val userDetails: UserDetails = userDetailsService
                .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.username)

        val jwt: String = jwtOperations.generateToken(userDetails)

        return ResponseEntity.ok(AuthenticationResponse(jwt))
    }
```

which I withdraw within @RequestHeader on another waypoints. I would like to provide also logging via facebook and gmail and I'm wondering how can I make it.

My current configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfiguration(
        private val userDetailsService: UserDetailsService,
        private val jwtRequestFilter: JwtRequestFilter
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
    }

    override fun configure(httpSecurity: HttpSecurity) {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(...).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): BCryptPasswordEncoder = BCryptPasswordEncoder(10)

    @Bean
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager = super.authenticationManagerBean()
```

JWTRequestfilter:

```
@Component
class JwtRequestFilter(
        @Qualifier("...") private val userDetailsService: UserDetailsService,
        private val jwtOperations: JwtOperations
) : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    override fun doFilterInternal(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {
        val authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization")

        var username: String? = null
        var jwt: String? = null

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader
            username = jwtOperations.extractUsername(jwt)
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication == null) {
            val userDetails: UserDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username)

            if (jwtOperations.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {
                val usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.authorities)
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.details = WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
}
```

I need to generate somehow JWT token when somebody has accomplished login with facebook. All tutorials I found are about integratin with for example facebook on client side (frontend). So my question is, how can I achieve this? How can I provide login with facebook/gmail so user does not have to create account by application.
Do you have any tutorials or sample projects? I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.0 and Kotlin, but I can read also tutorials with Java.

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 0):

I have created my OAuth2 with this link below.

The problems faced are

- Could not get the email for Github user
- Sign in by Apple has not been implemented yet.

Other than that this repo helped me a lot!!

https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo

Explanation

https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/

Comment: I just want to make it for facebook and google. I see in this repo there is also frontend. can I do it withotu frontend right now? Just have server side.

Comment: @traki111 Just copy the "spring-social" folder.